# SSH login warning message on a server with 2 DNS names

Tags: security, ssh, dns, remote-access

I am doing ssh to server x1.example.com from a laptop sometimes from outside and sometimes from lan. From lan I just say

```
ssh karl@x1
```

and from wan:

```
ssh karl@x1.example.com
```

But from lan I get always a warning: remote host identification has changed.

I can delete the other key in the known_hosts file each time, but I was wondering if there is a better solution.

I am hesitating to turn the key verification off, because this would be less secure. But getting a warning all the time is also unsecure (because I ignore such warnings all the time then)

Answer (score 4):

In known_hosts file you can list several names and even IP's for one key, for example:

```
x1,x1wan.example.com,192.168.0.134,23.41.51.23 ssh-rsa AAAA/bunch/of/gibberish/looking/data/==
```

But it is not your problem here. If you have a warning that host identification has changed it really means that. It means that between a moment of your first connection to this host from lan and now, somebody regenerated a host key for this host, for example while reinstalling the OS. Or that you have a man-in-the-middle attack.

Confirm with your admin that a host was reinstalled and host key regenerated and then remove old key from your known_hosts file. Next time you connect you'll add a new, correct key to known_hosts file and this warning will go away.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is actually one name, technically.

Assign a second host name (maybe via your hosts file) to access your server from the WAN: E.g.:

```
ssh karl@x1wan.example.com
```

I access a server via ssh with two different names (same IP) with no warnings.  E.g.: name1.example.com and name2.example.com

Comment: this is funny. thank you. i choosed the same name trying to avoid this problem.

Comment: If box x1 on the LAN and x1.example.com on the WAN resolve to a single IP then you don't need any of this!  Just ssh karl@x1.example.com.  (PS: If this works, don't forget to mark the answer as correct!)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for your answers.

Sorry folks, I lost my cookie based login and cannot rate or edit anymore. Your questions helped me to get around the problem when I change from LAN to WAN. I regard this question as solved.

But now I see the problem goes even deeper because I also have 2 hosts on the same IP, and the IP also changes, which I am covering (from my new account which I cannot loose anymore) in a new question with more details:

[How to handle ssh host key verification with 2 different hosts on the same (but changing) IP address?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/733753/how-to-handle-ssh-host-key-verification-with-2-different-hosts-on-the-same-but-c)