# How to handle ssh host key verification with 2 different hosts on the same (but changing) IP address?

Tags: security, ssh, verification, nat, openssh

I have 2 ssh servers behind a nat firewall at a location that changes its wan IP every day. They are always at the same wan IP address on a given time but on different ports.

I am connecting to server A this way:

```
ssh -p 22001 karl@x1.example.com
```

and to server B:

```
ssh -p 22002 karl@x2.example.com
```

So I get 2 different host keys for the same IP, and also when the IP changes even a different IP for the same host.

I have to go on deleting over and over the other key or the old key (in case of IP change) in the known_hosts file.

I am hesitating to turn the key verification off, because this would be less secure. But getting a warning all the time is also unsecure (because I ignore such warnings all the time then). Is there a better solution?

This is related to my old question here but not the same:

[SSH login warning message on a server with 2 DNS names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/696793/ssh-login-warning-message-on-a-server-with-2-dns-names)

Comment: why was this closed instead of moving to [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/)?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

I think this will work:

Create a `config` file in your `.ssh` directory as follows:

```
Host server1
  Hostname x1.example.com
  HostKeyAlias server1
  CheckHostIP no
  Port 22001
  User karl

Host server2
  Hostname x2.example.com
  HostKeyAlias server2
  CheckHostIP no
  Port 22002
  User karl
```

Explanation Below (from `man ssh_config`)

> **CheckHostIP**
>
> If this flag is set to
>   "yes", ssh(1) will additionally check
>   the host IP address in the known_hosts
>   file.  This allows ssh to detect if a
>   host key changed due to DNS spoofing. 
>   If the option is set to "no", the
>   check will not be executed.  The
>   default is "yes".
>
> **HostKeyAlias**
>
> Specifies an alias that should be used instead of the real
>   host name when looking up or saving the host key in the host key
>   database files.  This option is useful for tunneling SSH
>   connections or for multiple servers running on a single host.

The `Username` and `Port` line avoids you having to give those options on the command line, too, so you can just use:

```
% ssh server1
% ssh server2
```

Comment: Just wondering: is there a way to have ssh store the IP AND port in known_hosts? IIUC, this would allow some protection against DNS spoofing, right?

Comment: @Hbf on my MacOS X system the port (if non-standard) _is_ stored in `known_hosts`.

Comment: Not sure if that's a recent development, but OpenSSH at least as of v5.9 recognizes `host:22001` and `host:22002` as two separate hosts; thus, no warning "REMOTE HOST KEY HAS CHANGED".

Comment: One way to continue to allow spoofing detection is to specify a distinct UserKnownHosts file for each port on the same IP in the server config entries.