# Ansible access via SSH to Azure VM's on same host but different ports

Tags: azure, ssh, ansible

I have to VM's running on an azure cloud where the hostname is the same but the ports are different for the two VM's. I can do a direct SSH to each of the machines but now I'm trying to configure my ansible playbook to connect and run a simple ping command

```
ansible all -m ping
```

My basic ansible inventory file contained

```
[all]
test01vm0 ansible_host=test01.cloudapp.azure.com ansible_port=50000
test01vm1 ansible_host=test01.cloudapp.azure.com ansible_port=50001
```

The result is that first VM replies but the second always fails.

```
test01vm1 | UNREACHABLE! => {
    "changed": false, 
    "msg": "ERROR! SSH encountered an unknown error during the connection. We recommend you re-run the command using -vvvv, which will enable SSH debugging output to help diagnose the issue", 
    "unreachable": true
}
test01vm0 | SUCCESS => {
    "changed": false, 
    "ping": "pong"
}
```

I came across this thread on [how-to-handle-ssh-host-key-verification-with-2-different-hosts-on-the-same-but](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/733753/how-to-handle-ssh-host-key-verification-with-2-different-hosts-on-the-same-but) and i added
these details to my '.ssh/config' file

```
Host azure.t01vm0
    Hostname test01.cloudapp.azure.com
    HostKeyAlias azure.t01vm0
    CheckHostIP no
    Port 50000
    User admin

Host azure.t01vm1
    Hostname test01.cloudapp.azure.com
    HostKeyAlias azure.t01vm1
    CheckHostIP no
    Port 50001
    User admin
```

I then updated my inventory file to

```
[all]
test01vm0 ansible_host=azure.t01vm0
test01vm1 ansible_host=azure.t01vm1
```

which uses the host alias, under the hood the SSH command will resolve the Hostname and Port.

In my 'groups_vars/all' file i have

```
# ssh access
ansible_connection: ssh
~~ansible_user: admin~~
~~ansible_pass: xxxxx~~
```

In my 'ansible.cfg' file i have

```
[defaults]
~~host_key_checking=false~~
```

But the same issue still happens. Any suggestions on how i can get around this SSH issue?

The full error is

```
pc@pc-HP-ZBook-15:~/work/devops/ansible$ ansible all -m ping -vvvv
Using /home/pc/work/devops/ansible/ansible.cfg as config file
Loaded callback minimal of type stdout, v2.0
<azure.t01vm0> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: admin
<azure.t01vm0> SSH: EXEC ssh -C -vvv -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o User=admin -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/home/pc/.ansible/cp/ansible-ssh-%h-%p-%r -tt azure.t01vm0 '( umask 22 && mkdir -p "$( echo $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1453379274.37-334027235531 )" && echo "$( echo $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1453379274.37-334027235531 )" )'
<azure.t01vm1> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: admin
<azure.t01vm1> SSH: EXEC ssh -C -vvv -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o Port=50001 -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o User=admin -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/home/pc/.ansible/cp/ansible-ssh-%h-%p-%r -tt azure.t01vm1 '( umask 22 && mkdir -p "$( echo $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1453379274.37-107934098383321 )" && echo "$( echo $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1453379274.37-107934098383321 )" )'
test01vm1 | UNREACHABLE! => {
    "changed": false, 
    "msg": "ERROR! SSH encountered an unknown error. The output was:\nOpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014\r\ndebug1: Reading configuration data /home/pc/.ssh/config\r\ndebug1: /home/pc/.ssh/config line 20: Applying options for azure.t01vm1\r\ndebug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config\r\ndebug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *\r\ndebug1: Hostname has changed; re-reading configuration\r\ndebug1: Reading configuration data /home/pc/.ssh/config\r\ndebug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config\r\ndebug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *\r\ndebug1: auto-mux: Trying existing master\r\ndebug1: Control socket \"/home/pc/.ansible/cp/ansible-ssh-test01.cloudapp.azure.com-50001-admin\" does not exist\r\ndebug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0\r\ndebug1: Connecting to test01.cloudapp.azure.com [13.69.146.148] port 50001.\r\ndebug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK\r\ndebug1: fd 3 clearing O_NONBLOCK\r\ndebug1: Connection established.\r\ndebug3: timeout: 9975 ms remain after connect\r\ndebug3: Incorrect RSA1 identifier\r\ndebug3: Could not load \"/home/pc/.ssh/id_rsa\" as a RSA1 public key\r\ndebug1: identity file /home/pc/.ssh/id_rsa type 1\r\ndebug1: identity file /home/pc/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1\r\ndebug1: identity file /home/pc/.ssh/id_dsa type -1\r\ndebug1: identity file /home/pc/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1\r\ndebug1: identity file /home/pc/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1\r\ndebug1: identity file /home/pc/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1\r\ndebug1: identity file /home/pc/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1\r\ndebug1: identity file /home/pc/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1\r\ndebug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0\r\ndebug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.4\r\ndebug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.6.1\r\ndebug1: match: OpenSSH_6.6.1 pat OpenSSH_6.6.1* compat 0x04000000\r\ndebug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK\r\ndebug1: using hostkeyalias: azure.t01vm1\r\ndebug3: load_hostkeys: loading entries for host \"azure.t01vm1\" from file \"/home/pc/.ssh/known_hosts\"\r\ndebug3: load_hostkeys: found key type ECDSA in file /home/pc/.ssh/known_hosts:75\r\ndebug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys\r\ndebug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521\r\ndebug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent\r\ndebug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received\r\ndebug2: kex_parse_kexinit: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1\r\ndebug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,ssh-rsa,ssh-dss\r\ndebug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se\r\ndebug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se\r\ndebug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96\r\ndebug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96\r\ndebug2: kex_parse_kexinit: zlib@openssh.com,zlib,none\r\ndebug2: kex_parse_kexinit: zlib@openssh.com,zlib,none\r\ndebug2: kex_parse_kexinit: \r\ndebug2: kex_parse_kexinit: \r\ndebug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0 \r\ndebug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0 \r\ndebug2: kex_parse_kexinit: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1\r\ndebug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256\r\ndebug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se\r\ndebug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se\r\ndebug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96\r\ndebug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96\r\ndebug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com\r\ndebug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com\r\ndebug2: kex_parse_kexinit: \r\ndebug2: kex_parse_kexinit: \r\ndebug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0 \r\ndebug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0 \r\ndebug2: mac_setup: setup hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com\r\ndebug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com zlib@openssh.com\r\ndebug2: mac_setup: setup hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com\r\ndebug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com zlib@openssh.com\r\ndebug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT\r\ndebug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY\r\ndebug1: Server host key: ECDSA ff:e4:84:a7:d4:88:18:6b:80:a7:0c:df:b0:f1:56:16\r\ndebug3: put_host_port: [13.69.146.148]:50001\r\ndebug1: using hostkeyalias: azure.t01vm1\r\ndebug3: load_hostkeys: loading entries for host \"azure.t01vm1\" from file \"/home/pc/.ssh/known_hosts\"\r\ndebug3: load_hostkeys: found key type ECDSA in file /home/pc/.ssh/known_hosts:75\r\ndebug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys\r\ndebug1: Host 'azure.t01vm1' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.\r\ndebug1: Found key in /home/pc/.ssh/known_hosts:75\r\ndebug1: ssh_ecdsa_verify: signature correct\r\ndebug2: kex_derive_keys\r\ndebug2: set_newkeys: mode 1\r\ndebug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent\r\ndebug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS\r\ndebug2: set_newkeys: mode 0\r\ndebug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received\r\ndebug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent\r\ndebug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth\r\ndebug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received\r\ndebug2: key: /home/pc/.ssh/id_rsa (0x7fcac5e86a60),\r\ndebug2: key: /home/pc/.ssh/id_dsa ((nil)),\r\ndebug2: key: /home/pc/.ssh/id_ecdsa ((nil)),\r\ndebug2: key: /home/pc/.ssh/id_ed25519 ((nil)),\r\ndebug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password\r\ndebug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password\r\ndebug3: preferred gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey\r\ndebug3: authmethod_lookup gssapi-with-mic\r\ndebug3: remaining preferred: gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey\r\ndebug3: authmethod_is_enabled gssapi-with-mic\r\ndebug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-with-mic\r\ndebug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information\nNo Kerberos credentials available\n\r\ndebug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information\nNo Kerberos credentials available\n\r\ndebug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information\n\n\r\ndebug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information\nNo Kerberos credentials available\n\r\ndebug2: we did not send a packet, disable method\r\ndebug3: authmethod_lookup gssapi-keyex\r\ndebug3: remaining preferred: hostbased,publickey\r\ndebug3: authmethod_is_enabled gssapi-keyex\r\ndebug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-keyex\r\ndebug1: No valid Key exchange context\r\ndebug2: we did not send a packet, disable method\r\ndebug3: authmethod_lookup publickey\r\ndebug3: remaining preferred: ,publickey\r\ndebug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey\r\ndebug1: Next authentication method: publickey\r\ndebug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/pc/.ssh/id_rsa\r\ndebug3: send_pubkey_test\r\ndebug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply\r\ndebug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password\r\ndebug1: Trying private key: /home/pc/.ssh/id_dsa\r\ndebug3: no such identity: /home/pc/.ssh/id_dsa: No such file or directory\r\ndebug1: Trying private key: /home/pc/.ssh/id_ecdsa\r\ndebug3: no such identity: /home/pc/.ssh/id_ecdsa: No such file or directory\r\ndebug1: Trying private key: /home/pc/.ssh/id_ed25519\r\ndebug3: no such identity: /home/pc/.ssh/id_ed25519: No such file or directory\r\ndebug2: we did not send a packet, disable method\r\ndebug1: No more authentication methods to try.\r\nPermission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password).\r\n", 
    "unreachable": true
}
```

EDIT

I updated my ansible.cfg file to include a the private_key_file value

```
[defaults]
private_key_file=/home/pc/.ssh/id_rsa.pem
```

when i attempt to SSH onto the box with the private_key, this is the debug details and i get access

```
ssh -p 50000 admin@test01.cloudapp.azure.com -v -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pem 
OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/pc/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to test01.cloudapp.azure.com [40.112.77.99] port 50000.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/pc/.ssh/id_rsa.pem type -1
debug1: identity file /home/pc/.ssh/id_rsa.pem-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.4
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.6.1
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.6.1 pat OpenSSH_6.6.1* compat 0x04000000
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com none
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ECDSA a3:30:44:1a:1b:f9:fa:c0:6e:7e:79:a3:fe:da:f4:e1
debug1: Host '[test01.cloudapp.azure.com]:50000' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/pc/.ssh/known_hosts:67
debug1: ssh_ecdsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-keyex
debug1: No valid Key exchange context
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
No Kerberos credentials available
debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
No Kerberos credentials available
debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
No Kerberos credentials available
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: pc@pc-HP-ZBook-15
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 279
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to test01.cloudapp.azure.com ([40.112.77.99]:50000).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_IE.UTF-8
```

It seems odd to me that the SSH login is still using the 'publickey' in this case?

Comment: Can you please check the permission on the key you are using for test01vm1.

Comment: The permissions on my local '/home/pc/.ssh/id_rsa.pub' are '-rw-r--r--'.

Comment: What about the ownership of .pem file for test01vm1?

Comment: Where do you see reference to the '.pem' file?. There is one in the .ssh folder but it's only used for my azure command line client, as far as I'm aware.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a look on that long line, with error, you will find:

```
debug3: preferred gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey
```

Server does not support `password` authentication. It is no wonder that it fails. You need to allow it in server config or log in using private key.

Comment: Do you have an example of how i can change the ansible configure above to use the 'private key' ssh login when connecting?. I have removed the 'ansible_pass' variable from my global vars file.

Comment: Use your `ssh-agent`, `private_key_file=` option or  `--private-key` switch if the key is not passphrase protected as in [documentation](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_configuration.html#private-key-file)

Comment: I re-generated the key, and registered it with the ssh-agent. I've added the private_key_file details to the ansible config but I'm still seeing that SSH is using the publickey.

Comment: it is what you want, isn't it?